# scrollPane is not working so I want to know what is missing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to make a scroll bar work. It is already showing in the panel, but it acts like there's nothing below, so it doesn't go down. Here's my code (all library have been added):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));

panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

panel.setBounds(10, 66, 360, 705);

add(panel);

panel.setLayout(null);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

scrollPane.setBounds(345, 0, 20, 500);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);

scrollPane.setVisible(true);

panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,10));

scrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);

panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));

panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

panel.setBounds(10, 66, 360, 705);

panel.setLayout(null);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

scrollPane.setBounds(345, 0, 20, 500);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);

scrollPane.setVisible(true);

panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,10));

scrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);

add(scrollPane);
```

Note the change from add(panel) to add(scrollPane) as well as the new JScrollPane(panel); line

Comment: Didn't work for me. The panel disappeard and so did the scrollbar's buttons. still doesn't work. Thanks!